# php mysql select lowest value from multiple coloumn

Tags: php, mysql

i have database with this condition :

table hotel -----> table hotel price

table hotel :

```
hotel_id | hotel_name |
1            hotel1
2            hotel2
```

table hotel price

```
price_id |  hotel_id | room_type |  single | Double | extra |
1              1         superior      5       10        20
2              1          deluxe       3        5        10
```

and i would show start smallest price from hotel1

**hotel1   star from "smallest value"**

**i tried with this but not work**

```
$query = ("SELECT LEAST(COL1,COL2,COL3) FROM rug WHERE COL1 != '' AND COL2!= '' AND COL3 != ''");
$result=mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());}
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) 
{
$pricing[$i]=mysql_result($result, $i);
$i++;
}
sort($pricing);
$lowest_price = $pricing[0]; //lowest price
```

thank raymond for the answer this is almost correct

```
select
*
, least(single, `double`, extra) as lowest_price
from hotel_price
where
hotel_id = 1
order by
lowest_price
;
```

**with this will show lowest_price column at hotel price table**

PRICE_ID    HOTEL_ID    ROOM_TYPE   SINGLE  DOUBLE  EXTRA   HOTEL_NAME  LOWEST_PRICE
2             1              deluxe      3    5      10     hotel1             3
1             1              superior    5   10      20     hotel1             5

but i want just show one lowest price from lowest_price column

the smallest is **3**

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: First mysql_* functions are deprecated in PHP and should be used annymore use mysqli or PDO.. Can you place your tables and some example data on SQLFriddle (www.sqlfriddle.com) and could you redefine your question? because it isn't clear..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not completely sure if you need this..

if you know the id of hotel with name "hotel1" already

```
select
 *
 , least(single, `double`, extra) as lowest_price
from hotel_price
where
 hotel_id = 1
order by
 lowest_price
;
```

If you don't know the id of the hotel you need to join

```
select
 *
 , least(single, `double`, extra) as lowest_price
from
 hotel_price
inner join 
 hotel
on
 hotel_price.hotel_id = hotel.hotel_id
where
 hotel.hotel_name = 'hotel1'
order by
 lowest_price
;
```

see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f947b/3 for demo note the demo has more queries what should give you the same results

Answer (score 0):

By your SQL syntax I presume you are using MySQL. Than you can solve this by this approach:

```
SELECT

(SELECT COL1 from rug) as myField

UNION 
(SELECT COL2 from rug)

UNION 
(SELECT COL3 from rug)

order by myField ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Sure sure I didn't had noticed that :)